# Jetpack Compose LazyList Scroll Position

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I have *LazyColumn* which contains data i collect from viewmodel. Problem is when i change screen orientation or navigate to another composable and return, my composable can't save scrollstate. I'am not sure if i use *rememberLazyListState* correctly. Appreciate any help.

```
    @Composable
    fun UsersScreen(mainNavController: NavHostController, viewModel: UsersViewModel = hiltViewModel()) {
        val users = viewModel.users.collectAsState(listOf()).value
        val lazyListState = rememberLazyListState()
        Users(users, lazyListState, mainNavController)
    }
    
    @Composable
    fun Users(list: List<UserEntity>, listState: LazyListState, mainNavController: NavHostController) {
        LazyColumn(state = listState, modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
            items(list) { user ->
                UserCard(user) {
                    mainNavController.navigate("$USER_DETAIL/${user.fullName}")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you using Compose `beta07`? This is a known issue in [b/188567661](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/188567661) that is already fixed for beta08.

Comment: Yes, i am using beta07 version.  Since beta08 isn't released yet, i tried to downgrade it but it gives me IllegalStateException. Looks like i have to wait, thans a lot.

Comment: Although this is fixed if your list recomposes due to orientation changes, it is still a bug if the list is animated off screen with AnimatedVisibility. It will jump to the start of the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fixed in current version beta08.